# Stored Procedure Call from SQL Server to MYSQL over Linked Server

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am currently trying to build a process for checking SQL and MYSQL databases and am almost there thanks to the much help I have received on here.  My last issue and I am hoping that its an easy one is the following.  I have a SQL Server 2014 installation talking to a MYSQL database over a linked server.  I am able to run a select over the linked server without any issue now but when I run a stored procedure passing in some date variables I get the following error

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TESTCONNECTION" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TESTCONNECTION".
```

The Code I am running is

> SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY     (   TESTCONNECTION,'CALL
>   usp_sync_check_3(''2016-11-13'',''2016-11-15'');'     )

Am I not calling the stored procedure correction, when I run it from MySQL everything works fine, can anyone offer any suggestions.  I have been googling but nothing that seems to fix my issue.

Thanks P

Answer (score 1):

I have now figured this out, I was not passing in the schema name as well for the stored procedure, once I had done this everything worked as it should.  Thanks PJD